# Phonegap 2.3 and Android with HTML5 video tag in 2013

Tags: cordova, android-webview, html5-video

I know this has been asked many times and most have the same answer: "Use the videplayer plugin". But this is not the way some of us would like to play a video, we want to play in inline. And according to me there is not answer.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/10/partial-support-for-video-tag-in.html

Can any one give an answer that plays the video inline in the phonegap webview?

I know poeple are playing html5 video tags in the Android webview (inline), building their own webviews, so what is the problem with phonegap?

I mean can android devices seriously not play html5 video in the phonegap webview in 2013??

Even trying this: (apparently you cant play videos out off the assets folder)

```
<video id="1" autobuffer width="100%" tabindex="0">
         <source src="file:///videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
```

Does not work

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $("video")[0].play()
    });
</script>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
```

Comment: can you give more details about other people using video in their own webviews? as far as I know, the video tag "works" in phonegap, but not on all devices, I think only devices with android >= 4. BTW, read this blog post about inline video with phonegap >= 2.2.0 http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/partial-support-for-video-tag-in.html

Comment: from my example, is my file://video/../ correct?

Comment: also, my hardware accel is set to true

Comment: post the full code, not just the <source>

Comment: Simon coments on the blog post that it only works with files in the assets folder, http or using the file system API, try moving your videos to the phonegap www folder.

Comment: simons comment: At this time videos in the assets directory are not support so something like file:///android_asset/www/video.mp4 will not work.

Comment: You are right, I misread a comment on the blog.

Comment: I cant believe that Android sucks this much!!!!

Comment: Still struggling in 2014 and now, all these answers don't make sense anymore because the file structure has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem and created a plugin that accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example app](https://github.com/rjsteinert/HTML5VideoInAndroidWebViewExample) that, on the loadRemoteFileFromHTTP branch, successfully loads a video file in a webview from a remote location.  On the loadLocalFileUsingFileReader branch, the test.m4v file exists on the SD Card of he the device by being referenced as file:///mnt/sdcard/external_sd/test.m4v.  The gotcha is when you trying to include the video file in your App.  There's no way to use the file:/// protocol to reference something in your App and **you cannot use relative URLs for referencing videos in a WebView.** In other words, if you have your video file in your assets/www directory and you set src to "nameOfVideo.mp4", it plain won't work :(.  See the loadLocalFileUsingRelativeURL branch for an example.

[Here's a bug report on the Relative URL issue.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52334&thanks=52334&ts=1362127613)