# HTML5 video tag in phonegap android - its displays black screen but i can hear audio fine

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

My Application for android i am using,
PhoneGap 2.8.0

The video source form the SD card

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay autobuffer>
            <source src="file:///mnt/external_sd/app/test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

also i added  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in manifest file

but while playing video it show black screen but i can hear audio...

but if i playing from my site URL `http://site.com/test.mp4` it's playing good...

Why not from SD card... Is any setting i need to do?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810170/phonegap-2-3-and-android-with-html5-video-tag-in-2013

Comment: I already tried, that for PhoneGap old version...